# how can I solve x = t + sin(t) for t?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to understand how to approach solving the equation in the title. Any suggestions how to do it?

solve $x = t + \sin(t)$ for $t$

an approximation method that I can script into Matlab would be fine

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to solve for $t$ as a function of $x$:

We cannot solve for $t$ using only standard functions. We can, though, approximate what $t$ is, particularly when $x$ is large, by using the fact that $-1\leq \sin t \leq 1$.

Then, $$x = t + \sin(t)\iff t = x - \underbrace{\sin t}_{\in [-1,1]} \implies x - 1 \leq t \leq x+1$$

For VERY large $x$, the impact of $\sin t$ on the value $x - \sin t$ will be very minimal.

---

Given your edit (since rolled back):

If you are hoping to determine the range of $x$, given $\,t \in [0, \pi/2]$, e.g., then $0 \leq \sin t \leq 1$.

So the range of $x$ would be from $x = 0 + \sin 0 = 0\;$ to $\;x = \pi/2 + \sin(\pi/2) = \dfrac{\pi}2 + 1 = \dfrac{\pi + 2}{2}$.

Hence, $$x \in \left[0, \dfrac{\pi + 2}{2}\right]$$  Without knowing anything more about $t$, that's about all we can say.

Comment: ok, this makes sense. Thank you! It is just an engineering question in the end, so I realise now that I could make up a look-up table, calculating x from t, and then use that to find an approximation of t for a given x. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, Torben!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot express it in terms of sum of finite number of elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the value of the expression around a given point, $a$.

$t+\sin(t) \approx t+(t-a)+\sin(a)+\cos(a)\cdot(t-a)- \sin(a)\cdot (t-a)^2 \frac{1}{2!}-\cos(a)\cdot (t-a)^3\frac{1}{3!}.... $

This is called the Taylor approximation. If $a=0$ then it's usual to named Maclaurin approximation.

Answer (score 0):

- For [transcendental equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) **in general**, numerical approximation methods such as [Newton's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) (as well as others: see link) are usually employed.
- For small values of *t*, use the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for $\sin t\simeq t-\dfrac{t^3}{3!}$ , and then either apply the [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) yourself, or even ask *MatLab* to solve it directly, since it possesses in-build numerical methods for solving general *n*-th degree polynomials.
- For greater values of the argument, we have $t\simeq x$.